# git diff - listen for key press

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, git

I want to run the following commands:

```
git diff
git commit
```

`git commit` will open the default editor to edit the commit message. But if the difference if not too long it will close immediately.

How can I prevent closing `git diff` before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or other keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` uses `less` as a pager. If you want to use the pager on a specific, just pipe the output directly to `less` (`git` won't try to invoke `less` itself if it is outputting to a pipe, so no need to worry about have two `less` processes). Just do:

```
git diff | less
```

You could also add similar options to `less` that `git` does to get the same output, and add the `--color` option to `git diff` to get colour:

```
git diff --color | less -RSX
```

Comment: None of them has code highlight. Anyway, is a valid solution. +1

Comment: @IonicăBizău, just add `--color` to `git diff` and `-r` or `-R` to `less` to get colour.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the `git commit --verbose` command.  This will show the output of `git diff --staged` in your editor as you enter the commit message.

Comment: I really like `git commit --verbose`. I am going to use it. +1